# Cant run Luminus project on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, leiningen

I installed Leiningen on remote Ubuntu server 18.04 on Amazon EC2. After that I created a new application with the command "lein new luminus guestbook +h2" and started with "lein run". I got the following in my terminal:

```
2019-01-06 05:41:07,609 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: 
org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider 
2019-01-06 05:41:09,400 [main] INFO  guestbook.env - 
-=[guestbook started successfully using the development profile]=- 
2019-01-06 05:41:09,662 [main] INFO  luminus.http-server - starting HTTP 
server on port 3000 
2019-01-06 05:41:09,733 [main] DEBUG io.undertow - starting undertow server 
io.undertow.Undertow@51acd052 
2019-01-06 05:41:09,746 [main] INFO  org.xnio - XNIO version 3.3.6.Final 
2019-01-06 05:41:09,933 [main] DEBUG io.undertow - Configuring listener 
with protocol HTTP for interface 0.0.0.0 and port 3000 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,018 [main] INFO  org.projectodd.wunderboss.web.Web - 
Registered web context / 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,023 [main] INFO  guestbook.nrepl - starting nREPL 
server on port 7000 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,057 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - 
#'guestbook.db.core/*db* started 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,057 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - 
#'guestbook.handler/init-app started 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,058 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - 
#'guestbook.handler/app started 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,059 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - 
#'guestbook.core/http-server started 
2019-01-06 05:41:10,059 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - 
#'guestbook.core/repl-server started
```

BBut when I try to reach my app through the adress http://my-ipv4-public-ip:3000, It's without success. I did the same on my local ubuntu and I can access my app.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue.  Is that port open on the firewall?  `sudo ufw allow 3000`

Comment: Probably it's because port 3000 is not enabled by default in the EC2 security groups which define which inbound traffic is allowed. Check the docs here and create a new inbound rule for port 3000: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem.